# Indexing a column in list of lists

Tags: r, indexing

I have a list(RS_maja) that includes 28 sub-lists as you can see the 28th. I need to reach the third column of every list. It is `SENTINEL2B_20210627.153206.359_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1.0_CLM_R1` in this case.

I will apply a function to 28 list object's 3rd column using `lapply`. How can I index to the 3rd column?

```
RS_maja
.
.
.
[[28]]
              x      y SENTINEL2B_20210627.153206.359_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1.0_CLM_R1
    [1,] 347075 482915                                                       0
    [2,] 330675 453715                                                       0
    [3,] 362095 420345                                                      15
    [4,] 335225 398995                                                       0
    [5,] 403675 414815                                                      43
    [6,] 372505 476495                                                      11
    [7,] 326175 419255                                                       0
```

The function will use the third column as an input and will convert it to a label as; cloud, shadow, cirrus etc.

if I take not entire list but 4th element of the RS_maja;

```
RS_maja_4 = RS_maja[[4]] #this is the 4th element
y = RS_maja_4[,3]  #this is the 4th element's 3rd column.
```

```
maja_recode = recode_maja(y) #applying function
```

the output should be this;

```
[1] "clear" "clear" "clear" "clear" "cirrus" "clear" "cloud" "clear" "cloud" "cloud"
```

In case I'm defining the data type incorrectly;

```
> class(RS_maja) 
[1] "list" 
> class(RS_maja[1]) 
[1] "list" 
>class(RS_maja[[1]]) 
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

To be more clear about data;

```
dput(RS_maja[1:2])
```

```
list(structure(c(330705, 320285, 320755, 384575, 301815, 390405, 
387755, 372615, 407025, 372185, 336095, 323595, 359375, 308295, 
325545, 386115, 334005, 341105, 344615, 358975, 328335, 344205, 
386655, 400125, 367975, 341625, 363715, 304255, 339365, 338405, 
407135, 381845, 394775, 332125, 334235, 348075, 352955, 393625, 
348885, 402705, 378825, 370295, 370385, 345945, 336025, 378665, 
380875, 381755, 409175, 341645, 310925, 372675, 357915, 351285, 
380755, 351345, 352405, 400375, 317765, 383275, 343295, 394445, 
303715, 352375, 387155, 354515, 356545, 386665, 309345, 303015, 
342545, 408835, 352555, 358155, 407895, 343965, 335115, 403605, 
348125, 396395, 380895, 349965, 346605, 345825, 382005, 330215, 
399175, 371955, 392965, 340835, 340135, 326925, 345685, 339815, 
354965, 377925, 390145, 403265, 336135, 379995, 434965, 445435, 
466335, 440165, 465555, 476965, 446665, 407225, 429185, 396565, 
438755, 495025, 427235, 417295, 464685, 478125, 400855, 434875, 
495415, 477365, 439805, 469125, 472305, 422625, 437605, 454675, 
490715, 483055, 476555, 423585, 465115, 499865, 499945, 492705, 
397205, 414065, 437735, 420595, 395905, 461075, 452585, 477075, 
423365, 462305, 402925, 469195, 451155, 443765, 410005, 443475, 
424815, 475405, 390275, 397575, 484415, 454705, 491955, 482515, 
497075, 465325, 408005, 450005, 493705, 496565, 412305, 402155, 
426195, 440225, 393985, 408585, 406905, 499415, 481195, 465315, 
485315, 397085, 403925, 444215, 462085, 466595, 415205, 459265, 
429075, 413315, 496925, 424875, 396905, 464645, 453035, 430675, 
403635, 459305, 478405, 456795, 407105, 449675, 444265, 442225, 
462605, 482265, 7, 135, 135, 0, 135, 11, 0, 7, 0, 0, 135, 135, 
135, 135, 135, 143, 135, 135, 135, 7, 7, 135, 143, 0, 135, 135, 
7, 135, 135, 7, 0, 143, 159, 135, 135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 
143, 7, 135, 0, 143, 135, 0, 0, 135, 135, 143, 135, 135, 143, 
135, 135, 0, 131, 139, 7, 0, 135, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 135, 
0, 0, 135, 135, 0, 131, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 135, 0, 143, 0, 
0, 143, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 0, 0, 135, 143), .Dim = c(100L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y", "SENTINEL2B_20210210.154159.565_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1.0_CLM_R1"
))), structure(c(359325, 381165, 401365, 391895, 327755, 373585, 
378995, 398995, 406355, 323235, 362275, 384855, 387285, 347885, 
360645, 399995, 333365, 353135, 393875, 387535, 326115, 373335, 
306075, 310365, 336195, 370455, 395805, 334215, 358015, 334675, 
342595, 385315, 376455, 403275, 346235, 335065, 336805, 317345, 
360725, 367585, 408485, 346575, 348155, 346095, 406225, 371015, 
330335, 395595, 377255, 374375, 348135, 357585, 300155, 394355, 
311835, 407725, 312145, 385535, 348695, 365905, 382225, 367815, 
319815, 314315, 304715, 343995, 340755, 376495, 321115, 327335, 
378645, 393075, 336965, 344825, 328465, 359545, 359675, 367705, 
321105, 393505, 375855, 319285, 314915, 338395, 347065, 393355, 
384005, 344045, 400425, 348935, 392815, 350105, 374365, 377395, 
330165, 398365, 337275, 317405, 331735, 367695, 397205, 497905, 
444105, 440545, 395215, 405035, 445815, 406665, 412875, 478945, 
471755, 401945, 487995, 464875, 421825, 475425, 476245, 424155, 
461915, 494215, 416425, 461245, 390745, 422985, 398595, 415725, 
480145, 440785, 423345, 484985, 392825, 399825, 474345, 448545, 
453265, 393075, 461325, 477845, 415295, 410445, 399195, 444335, 
448555, 452195, 490695, 475525, 426865, 445635, 411415, 391625, 
435195, 428235, 434675, 492865, 426965, 478475, 491075, 440845, 
464315, 458805, 445535, 475955, 492995, 473395, 438965, 417275, 
451835, 447655, 459985, 462765, 462155, 406555, 479145, 491835, 
435655, 485975, 438485, 454545, 455895, 432045, 449835, 445365, 
453805, 404835, 412035, 412635, 496375, 475835, 495545, 485925, 
436525, 426925, 493045, 444765, 494965, 401345, 420305, 475835, 
421935, 460305, 131, 155, 7, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 143, 
0, 135, 7, 0, 0, 7, 159, 0, 143, 0, 0, 0, 135, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
7, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 131, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 7, 143, 0, 7, 7, 7, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 
143, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 131, 0, 7, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 143, 0, 
31, 0, 7, 0, 131, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 155), .Dim = c(100L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("x", "y", "SENTINEL2B_20210217.153203.301_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1.0_CLM_R1"
    ))))
```

Comment: Try `lapply(RS_maja, function(x) x[,3])`

Comment: the function is called **recode_maja** not a built-up function, the third column will be the input. when I did your suggestion I got this error `RS_maja[, 3] : incorrect number of dimensions`. I think I could not apply your suggestion in a good way.  @akrun

Comment: I assumed that you have a `list` of `matrices` like `RS_maja <- replicate(28, matrix(rnorm(3 * 15), ncol = 3), simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: If this is a list of lists, then do `lapply(RS_maja, function(sublst) lapply(sublst, function(x) x[,3]))` Reproudcuible example `set.seed(24);RS_maja <- replicate(3, replicate(28, matrix(rnorm(3 * 15), ncol = 3), simplify = FALSE), simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: `> class(RS_maja)
[1] "list"
> class(RS_maja[1])
[1] "list"
> class(RS_maja[[1]])
[1] "matrix" "array"`
Why do we use   `rnorm(3 * 15) ` ?? 

the third column will be the input of my function.

Comment: Sorry.  I was showing a reproducible example to show that my code works in that case.

Comment: Can you try the code I showed i.e. `lapply(RS_maja, function(sublst) lapply(sublst, function(x) x[,3]))`

Comment: I was already trying it and had this `Error in x[, 3] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: You may need to show the `str` or `dput` of a small data as these were based on assumptions and your descripitons that it is a list of list of matrix

Comment: if I apply this function to 1 list without applying with lapply;

```y = RS_maja_m[,3] ``` #the third column that I wanted to use
```maja_recode = recode_maja(y)```

output;
`[1] "clear" "clear" "clear" "clear" "cirrus" "clear" "cloud" "clear" "cloud" "cloud"`
The function labels the the 3rd column values as cloud, clear, cirrus.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @GKi something is missing on that code. `Error: unexpected '[' in "lapply(lapply(RS_maja, [" `

Comment: @RS_girl Maybe something like `lapply(lapply(RS_maja, \`[\`, 3), recode_maja)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a list of data.frames

**You can use purrr::map**

An example with a custom function and a toy list:

```
#Create toy list
a<-list(one=data.frame(a=1:2, b=2:3, c=3:4), two=data.frame(a=1:2, b=2:3, c=3:4))
```

```
#create custom function

my_function<-function(x) {x*2}
```

Apply custom function in a loop to every third list element

```
library(purrr)

map(a, 3) %>% map(my_function)

#OR

map(a, ~ my_function(.x[3]))
```

If you need to do it in base R, you can use:

```
lapply(a, function(x) my_function(x[[3]])
```

Output

```
$one
[1] 6 8

$two
[1] 6 8
```

Comment: The function labels the the 3rd column values as cloud, clear, cirrus. When I apply your suggestion I got this; 
`> a = map(RS_maja, ~recode_maja(.x[3]))
> a
[[1]]
[1] "cloud"

[[2]]
[1] "cirrus"

[[3]]
[1] "cirrus" `

but I've got 10000 pixels to be labelled. this result only gives 1 label.

Comment: We can only help you so much without a proper reproducible example. Please edit your question if you want further help. Providing your sample function and at an example list with some of the elements from the original list would do the trick. You could paste the output of `dput(RS_maja[1:2])` and your function.

Comment: okay but my function is 90+line code. So it is not nice to fill here with this. but I will try to explain more specific.